# How to test GAZEBO works properly. Save windows don't show any component

Tags: gazebo

How can I test whether my gazebo installation works properly or not? I'm trying to "save myworld" and "save as" options but no window is shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Save World as" is broken on Gazebo 5.1.0 .

You can either install the experimental version of Gazebo 6 using the `gazebo6-prerelease` package (assuming you are on Ubuntu) or wait for the fix to be released in Gazebo 5.2.0 .

The relevant bug on Gazebo issue tracker is:
https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/1593/world-save-as-broken-on-gazebo-510 .

Comment: This is still broken as of the latest: Gazebo 11 on Ubuntu 20.

Comment: Not sure if it is related, but there is a similar issue on Gazebo issue tracker: https://github.com/osrf/gazebo/issues/2866 .